# The last & the first day of a month in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, worksheet-function

How to get the first and last day of the previous month in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you had your base date in `A1`,
this will return the date of the **last day of the previous month**:

```
=eomonth(A1,-1)
```

For the date of the **first day of the previous month**, this is the shortest way:

```
=eomonth(A1,-2)+1
```

Also possible:

```
=date(year(A1),month(A1)-1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your supply, unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe due to the french version i am using? To me formula must be in english even if i am french but maybe it changed some weeks ago ...

Comment: OK it works => =date(year(A1), month(A1)-1,1) thank you Zygd

Comment: And for first day of next (and subsequent months):
`=date(year(A1),month(A1)+1,1)`

Answer (score 5):

for the last day of the previous month  (international)

```
=eomonth(now();-1)
```

for the last day of the previous month  (USA)

```
 =eomonth(now(),-1)
```

for the first day of the previous month (international)

```
=eomonth(now();-2)+1
```

for the first day of the previous month (USA)

```
    =eomonth(now(),-2)+1
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `=eomonth((eomonth(today(),0)),-2)+1` for use when you want previous from today.

For the last day of the previous month, use `=eomonth((eomonth(today(),0)),-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Cell A1 To Contain:

```
=eomonth(A2,-1)+1
```

Cell A2 To Contain:

```
=Eomonth(now(),)
```

if instead of using "now()" you can put in another cells reference, or even do a query/importrange for a particular cell from a different sheet and make these dates even more dynamic.